# Itunes Connect - Reject Binary

Tags: app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

I have a problem in itunes connect where I need to reject my binary. If I do reject my binary will it delete all of my current information (description, screenshots, etc)?
Should I save this info before rejecting my binary?

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I have done so therefore it may have changed, but rejecting binary will not delete your metadata. The metadata persists between versions of the app too (with a few exceptions).

Comment: It is as you say, Dan. Rejecting a binary doesn't mean removing all metadata information, that will be kept. I have done it many times and the only thing you need to change at iTunesConnect is pressing the "ready to submit" button. Then submit your new binary through XCode.